# Overwriting the text in slot

Tags: windows, qt, chat, overwrite, slot

I am designing a chat application. My query is that I am printing the message and name of the user in a chat box on pressing a send button in Qt. Every time I press the button instead of writing the new message in next line, it erases the previous message and overwrites it by showing the new message only.

Code:

```
QString str = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QString name= ui->textEdit->objectName();
    ui->textBrowser->setText(name);
    ui->textBrowser->setText(name + ": " + str);
    std::cout<<endl;
```

Comment: setText() sets the complete text - so it's doing what you told it to do. If you want to append the new text you have to retrieve the old one via QTextBrowser::text()

Answer (score 0):

`setText()` sets the text in the textEdit (and not appends what you have probably guessed), therefore your second `setText()` overwrites the first one.

```cpp
    QString str = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QString name= ui->textEdit->objectName();
    
    QString oldMsg = ui->textBrowser->text();
    QString newMsg = name + ": " + str;

    ui->textBrowser->setText(oldMsg + "\n" + newMsg);
```